# What version of Visual Studio 2008... Does "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2.0" INCLUDES vs2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed. But for a client I do need Visual Studio 2008 (to avoid some upgrades that are note compatible with vs2010)

It is my job's notebook, so everything must be original and legal. And both, the client and my boss want to avoid licences costs. ANYWAY... it seems that my notebook already has some version of vs2008, I need to know if it is too muche reduced or if it will work to develop.

I can open a vs2008 that seems pretty much the same, also the about screen. But at "Add or Remove Programs" I just only have "Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2.0"

Finnaly when I run the app, it works, but the code is not recognize, it is shown as it is notepad.

Here are some screenshots that may help... THANKS ALL!!

[image: Add or Remove Programs filtered by "Visual Studio"]
[image: vs2008 about]
[image: vs2010 about]
[image: vs2008 vs vs2010 folder sizes]

Comment: You have the *shell* version of VS2008, it is not the same thing as the IDE.  It can be used by anybody to develop an app that uses the VS user interface, the shell can be freely deployed to anybody.  It isn't clear what app that might be but "Tools for Applications 2.0" is a good candidate.  All of this is free with a click-through license, it doesn't have anything to do with what you need.  You'll need an MSDN subscription, an excellent way to never have to bother your boss again about licenses.

Answer (score 1):

VSTA is sort of a replacement for VBA, i.e. you can use VS to write .NET code to extend and automate thrid-party applications that are designed to support it.  It appears that that is the only VS 2008 component that you have installed so you cannot open VB or C# projects or any of that stuff.  If you want a legal copy of VS 2008 that you don't have to pay for then you'll need to look at an Express edition, although that may lack some features that you need.  2008 Express editions are hard to come by now too, as they are not offered for download any more by Microsoft.

What are these non-upgradeable parts of your project?

Comment: About the non-upgradeable parts. The project is many years old, it had a silverlight UI that is no longer used, now UI is asp.net, but there is still some dependences as WCF RIA Services BETA, that is not compatible with vs2010, I must upgrade it to WCF RIA Services v1.0 but to do so, I also must install silverlight 4 and update from .net 3.5 to 4 or greater, and that would be too much.

Comment: I think that you should be OK with Express in that case but I'm not 100% sure.